# Why is my JSF session always recreated? (when accessed with double slash in the URL)

Tags: jsf, session, jsf-2

I have run into a very weird problem giving me headache.  My Session scoped bean is always recreated when I reload a specific page.  The bean loses all its informations and the session id is always new.  AFAIK this is an anormal behavior.

I think I have managed to reproduce the problem with the following code :

**sessionTest.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html
  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

<h:body>

  <!-- Fake call to initSession to force creating the bean --> 
  <h:outputText value="#{sessionTestC.initSession()}"></h:outputText>

  <h:outputText value="#{sessionTestC.sessionId}"></h:outputText>

</h:body>

</html>
```

**SessionTestController.java**

```
package myapp.beans.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.annotation.PreDestroy;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@SessionScoped
@ManagedBean(name="sessionTestC")
public class SessionTestController  implements Serializable {

  /**
   * 
   */
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -6024842251492695682L;

  private String sessionId = null;

  @PostConstruct
  public void reset () {
    System.out.println("creating sessionTestC!");
  }

  @PreDestroy
  public void destroy () {
    System.out.println("destroying sessionTestC!");
  }

  public void initSession() {
    System.out.println("Init session...");

    FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fCtx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    sessionId = session.getId(); 
  }

  public String getSessionId() {
    FacesContext fCtx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    HttpSession session = (HttpSession) fCtx.getExternalContext().getSession(false);
    sessionId = session.getId(); 
    return sessionId; 
  }

  public void setSessionId(String sessionId) {
    this.sessionId = sessionId;
  }

}
```

Every time I reload the `sessionTest.xhtml` page I get a new session Id.  In the console I can see : creating sessionTestC! | Init session... | creating sessionTestC! | Init session...

Obviously I'm doing something wrong but I can't find what.  I'm using JSF 2.1.19.

Comment: I run your example on JBoss 7.1.1 and everything works fine - the bean is initialized once and session id is the same for all subsequent requests. Did you try with newer version of JSF library? Could you provide more details on the environment you are using?

Comment: @DawidPytel Sorry if I didn't reply.  Your comment made me realize that this code is fine and that there was something else.  I think I found the problem : if I call `http://localhost:8080/TestBean/sessionTest.xhtml` everything is fine but if I call `http://localhost:8080//TestBean/sessionTest.xhtml` (notice the double `//` after the port) then the bean is created on very request! Any reason for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in comments session scoped beans work perfectly fine.

The problem is double slash in URL after port `http://localhost:8080//TestBean/sessionTest.xhtml`. For some reason all popular browsers (FF, IE, Chrome) do not send cookies for such URL. Because `JSESSIONID` cookie is not sent to a server a new session is created by the server.